# Horizontal Rule between <div>'s

Tags: html, css

Right now, I have 3 divs Content1, Content2, Content3

I want to add a simple stylized rule to separate the content in each. Here is the code that I am working with.

HTML

```
     <div id="Content1">
     <p><strong>Content1</strong></p>
     </div>

     <div id="Content2">
     <p><strong>Content2</strong></p>
     </div>

     <div id="Content3">
     <p><strong>Content3</strong></p>
     </div>
```

I want to add a Horizontal Rule inbetween Content1 and Content2 and between Content2 and Content3.

I have included an image so you can see exactly what I mean.

[image]

Comment: I take it you don't want to use <hr /> tags?

Comment: <hr> tags are fine, but dont seem to work inbetween divs? Maybe im an noobie

Comment: No, they work between divs.  You should just be able to throw in a <hr /> between each set of divs.

Comment: hr and compatibility with old IEs and precise vertical margins is a nightmare. Don't. And here it's just presentational, you rarely have a HR after each paragraph...

Comment: Can you provide a snippet through Snippet editor?

Answer (score 18):

Don't use `<hr>` for this, as it's chiefly a semantic element rather than presentational. A bottom border is ideal for this. E.g. http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/pjbkA

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

div {width: 500px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
#Content1, #Content2 {border-bottom: 3px solid #4588ba; margin-bottom:10px;}
div p {background: #4588ba; line-height: 150px; font-size: 2em; font-family: sans-serif; color: white; margin: 0; padding-left: 30px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

     <div id="Content1">
     <p><strong>Content1</strong></p>
     </div>

     <div id="Content2">
     <p><strong>Content2</strong></p>
     </div>

     <div id="Content3">
     <p><strong>Content3</strong></p>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason for bottom rather than top?

Comment: No, either is fine. :-)

Comment: Listing multiple div id's in your css, when all those divs get identical styling, is inefficient and error-prone. The CSS way to do it is to make a class, and apply the same class to all those divs. Even better, if every sibling div has the same styling, is to use a selector instead of  a class, `#parent-div > div`. Finally, if you're trying to target pre-CSS3 browsers, create one style for just the last sib `Content3`

Comment: Yeah, I would never use IDs like that. Was just adapting the code supplied by the OP.

Comment: @ralph.m The `<hr/>` element is literally a zero-height element with a bottom border and a little margin.

Comment: @MfyDev — It might depend on the browser. In Chrome it appears to have all 4 borders if you zoom in. Anyhow, the `hr` element has (or *used* to have) semantic value (separating sections of content, a bit like a heading), so that's why I suggested just using CSS alone. (This post was also about ten years ago!)

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `hr` tag to separate your `div` elements

```
<div id="Content1">
     <p><strong>Content1</strong></p>
</div>
<hr />
     <div id="Content2">
     <p><strong>Content2</strong></p>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="Content3">
     <p><strong>Content3</strong></p>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BCn8b/)

You can reset the default 3d style of an `hr` tag using [**solid border**](http://jsfiddle.net/BCn8b/1/)

```
hr {
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: this solution quickly becomes unmanageable on a page with many div's.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to use hr tag. you can bound every div with another div and decorate it. Like this: 
See demo at : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/james_nguyen/4Ca4w/7/)

```
<div id="Content1" class="divOutside">
    <div class="divInside">
        <strong>Content1</strong>       
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Content2" class="divOutside">
    <div class="divInside">
       <strong>Content2</strong>        
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Content3" class="divOutside last">
    <div class="divInside">
       <strong>Content3</strong>     
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Css:

```
.divOutside {
    border-bottom:2px blue solid;
    width:200px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.divInside {
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:blue;
}
.last {
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vRQyN/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="Content1" class="content">
     <p><strong>Content1</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="break"></div>
     <div id="Content2" class="content">
     <p><strong>Content2</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="break"></div>
     <div id="Content3" class="content">
     <p><strong>Content3</strong></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    padding:20px;
    background:#3E87BC;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #FFF;
}
.break { 
    background: #3E87BC;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: easier to just use `hr`

Answer (score -3):

```
<div id="Content1" style="background-color:#2554C7;width:300px;height:50px;">
<p style="padding-left:40px;padding-top:10px;color:white;font-size:26px;"><strong>Content1</strong></p>
</div>
<div id="Content4" style="background-color:#2554C7;width:300px;height:5px;">
<hr style="color:#2554C7;"></hr>
</div>
<div id="Content2" style="background-color:#2554C7;width:300px;height:50px;">
<p style="padding-left:40px;padding-top:10px;color:white;font-size:26px;"><strong>Content2</strong></p>
</div>
<div id="Content5" style="background-color:#2554C7;width:300px;height:5px;">
<hr style="color:#2554C7;"></hr>
</div>
<div id="Content3" style="background-color:#2554C7;width:300px;height:50px;">
<p style="padding-left:40px;padding-top:10px;color:white;font-size:26px;"><strong>Content3</strong></p>
</div>
<div id="Content6" style="background-color:#2554C7;width:300px;height:5px;">
<hr style="color:#2554C7;"></hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats quite a crazy way to do it :p

Comment: In my opinion you shouldn't encourage inline styling.  It would be a terrible mess if you wanted to change something universally.

Comment: Crazy because redundancy. The whole point of CSS is to eliminate redundancy and reduce effort.