# line with css below each div

Tags: html, css, line

I am trying to show a line below each div in a container. Instead of using `<hr>` tag every time, do we have option to handle this with css?

Html Code

```css
#LinksContainer hr {
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div id="LinksContainer">
  <div><a href="#" target="_blank">Forum1</a></div>
  <hr/>
  <div><a href="#" target="_blank">Forum2</a></div>
  <hr/>
  <div><a href="#" target="_blank">Forum3</a></div>
  <hr/>
  <div><a href="#" target="_blank">Forum4</a></div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: `border-bottom`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705620/horizontal-rule-between-divs

Comment: Here's a fiddle using `border-bottom`, just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/tEdXL/

Comment: duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705620/horizontal-rule-between-divs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add css attribute `border-bottom: 1px solid grey;` for example

Here is a syntax:

```
border-bottom: [border-width || border-style || border-color] | inherit
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the border? In my case I'm already using the border and need another line of some sort, created with css.